# Optional in swift 4

Tags: ios, swift4

```
//View Controller
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
final let url = URL(string : "https://simplifiedcoding.net/demos/view-flipper/heroes.php")
var HeroesArray : [Hero] = []
var dict = NSDictionary()

var cellReuseIdentifier = "HeroId"
@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self
    self.tableView.register(HeroClass.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: cellReuseIdentifier)
    downloadJson()
}

func downloadJson(){
    guard let finalURL = url else { return }
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: finalURL) { data, urlresponse, error in
    guard let data = data, error == nil, urlresponse != nil else{
        print("Something Wrong")
        return
        }
        do{
            let decoder = JSONDecoder()
            let sathish =  try decoder.decode(Heroes.self, from:data)
            self.HeroesArray = sathish.heroes
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }
        }catch{
            print(error)
            print("Something Went Wrong after Download")
        }
    }.resume()
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return HeroesArray.count
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{
    let cell : HeroClass = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellReuseIdentifier) as! HeroClass!
    print(cell)
    print(HeroesArray[indexPath.row].name)
    cell.HeroName?.text = HeroesArray[indexPath.row].name
   print(cell.HeroName?.text)
    if let imageURL = URL(string: HeroesArray[indexPath.row].imageurl){
        DispatchQueue.global().async {
            let data = try? Data(contentsOf: imageURL)
            if let data = data {
                let image = UIImage(data: data)
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    cell.imageLabel?.image = image
                    //print(image)
                }
        }
    }
}
    return cell
}
}
```

Cannot get the cell.HeroName?.text & cell.imageLabel?.image value. Both Values points to nil. Please help me to Solve . Thanks in Advance

Comment: are you get the value here `print(HeroesArray[indexPath.row].name)`

Comment: Maybe issues is not with the optional, First please confirm that you are getting the Response from the API buy print the `print(HeroesArray[indexPath.row].name)` in the Console. and please provide the appropriate number of breaking point and debug it line by line.

Comment: I got response from the API.

Comment: Sounds good. Let me show you a piece of code that may help you. Have you any idea about the Codable? @SathishP

Comment: Kindly please give me the code.

Comment: I ll post the Dropbox link can you please check the code and tell me what is the issue.

Comment: sure, Wait for a while I'll catch you after the lunch

Comment: please send the complete project file. Without that i cant open the project file.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/ggy6ail7qs12xlb/AADo7B0D7O8ClMZdMwLq1Nrya?dl=0

Comment: please change the code and post that as a link so that i can use the file in future. Thanks

Comment: Is that okay? @krunalnagvadia

Comment: [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1LTuYAU-e2fT_-WVULSGgTVIXg_J6sDey/view?usp=sharing) 

Check this project implement as per that. Let me know if you have still any quires.

Comment: the task is without using alarmofire library.

Comment: cell.HeroName.text! = HeroesArray[indexPath.row].name  i m getting runtime error in this line. The error is : Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value.. as well as in cell.imageLabel.image! line also. Please let me know why? @KrunalNagvadia

Comment: Error is appear in your code OR in my given code?

Comment: Error is in my code.

Answer (score 0):

If your `Heroes` and `Hero` entities are like this

```
struct Hero: Decodable {
    let name: String
    let imageurl: String
}

struct Heroes: Decodable {
    let heroes: [Hero]
}
```

Then your following code should work fine

```
let url = URL(string : "https://simplifiedcoding.net/demos/view-flipper/heroes.php")
var heroes: [Hero] = []
var dict = NSDictionary()

guard let finalURL = url else { return }
URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: finalURL) { data, urlresponse, error in
    guard let data = data, error == nil, urlresponse != nil else{
        print("Something Wrong")
        return
    }

    do {
        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        let sathish =  try decoder.decode(Heroes.self, from:data)
        self.heroes = sathish.heroes
        print(heroes)
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    } catch {
        print(error)
        print("Something Went Wrong after Download")
    }
}.resume()
```

Comment: @SathishP It's working/running perfectly fine (Swift 4.2), `heroes` returns the array of `Hero` objects. Just replace `self.heroes` with `self.HeroesArray` (just for the convention). One more keep your `var` first letter small. If you are still facing issues, share the error you are getting